# Draw image in mac os

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, osx-lion

I need to draw an image in mac os project. In iOS I can do this using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.
Please give me an example, how to draw image in mac os or give an analog of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to draw into an NSImage, you'll want:

```
NSImage* anImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(100.0,  100.0)];
[anImage lockFocus];

// Do your drawing here...

[anImage unlockFocus];
```

From the Cocoa drawing [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html).